# highlight wrong date value in excel or google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am facing a problem in one of the projects that when import data , some dates are incorrect

31 April for example, which is not a correct value

I want to be able to highlight the cells with incorrect values to revise it with client

is there any possible way to do that in google sheet or excel

Answer (score 3):

in gs you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ISDATE_STRICT(A1:A2))
```

[image]

or if you want to paint it:

```
=NOT(ISDATE(A1))*(A1<>"")
```

[image]